# Logical help - java regex

Tags: java, android, regex, logic

I have a string which contains image tags, more than 1. Now I need to regex out the `alt=` tag. I tried it like this:

```
while (m3.find()) {
    Pattern p4 = Pattern.compile("<!\\[CDATA\\[(.*?)\\]\\]>");
    Matcher m4 = p4.matcher(m3.group());

    while (m4.find()) {
         if(m4.group().contains("<img src")) {
            Pattern p6 = Pattern.compile("<img src(.*?)/>");
        Matcher m6 = p6.matcher(m4.group());

        while (m6.find()) {
                Pattern p7 = Pattern.compile("alt=\"(.*?)\"");
                Matcher m7 = p7.matcher(m6.group());

            while (m7.find()) {
messages.add(m4.group().replace(m6.group(), m7.group().replace("alt=",  "").replace("\"", "")).replace("<![CDATA[", "").replace("]]>", ""));
                                } 
                            }
                        } else {
                            messages.add(m4.group().replace("<![CDATA[", "").replace("]]>", ""));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The problem is: there is more than 1 image tag. `messages` is an ArrayList. I need just 1 `messages.add` for ALL images in the actual message. The code as it is does something very different and I don't have any idea how to fix it or where my mistakes are :/ I just want replace the whole  with the content of `alt="..."`, but every  the actual message contains. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use a third party library like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), which allows parsing, extracting and modifying html documents in a jquery fashion. Using this library, changing the attributes of certain html elements (as [explained here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-attributes)) should work like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select("div.comments a").attr("rel", "nofollow");
```